# expression engine: Content in channel fields don't show up on the webpage when called in a template

Tags: expressionengine

I have a snippet called sidebar with the following code.

```
<div id="ebook_offer">
{exp:channel:entries channel="test"}
<h3>Ebook</h3>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</div>

<div id="about_blog">
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog_sidebar"}
        <h3>About Obsia's Blog</h3>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</div>

<div id="testimonials">
</div>

<div id="demo" dynamic="no" limit="1">
</div>

<div id="recent posts">
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit=5 offset=1}
        <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
                <li>{title}</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</div>

<div "connect">
</div>

<div = "subscribe">
{exp:mailinglist:form list="blog_list" form_id="blog_subscribe"}
        <h3>Subscribe</h3>
        <p>First Name <input type="text" name="first_name"="{first_name}"></p>
        <p>Email <input type="text" name="email" value="{email}"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
{/exp:mailinglist:form}
</div>
```

This snippet is called inside the index.php template for blog template group and the code is as follows:

```
<div id="blog_display">
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="5"}
  <h2>{title}</h2>
  {author}
  {if blog_images} <img src="{blog_images}" alt="blog image {title}" class="some_class" />
  {/if}
  {teaser}
  <p>comments {comment_total} </p>
{/exp:channel:entries} 
</div>

{sidebar}
```

I also have channel called sidebar with fields such as ebook_offer, about_blog, recast posts, testimonials, subscribe. I can get the subscribe forms to show up. I can see recent posts on my webpage but can't see any of the content that has been filled in about_blog field.

Anyone know why blog channel works but not my sidebar channel.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what the problem is exactly without having all of your code in front of me, but it could be a few things. For starters, if your blog homepage template has an `{exp:channel:entries}` tag in it, and you're including the snippet *inside* of that tag, you'd run into problems. You can't nest an `{exp:channel:entries}` inside of another.

Also, channel entry tags are set to *dynamic* by default. They will look at the URL for hints about what entries to pull from the database. Try adding the `dynamic="no"` parameter to your sidebar entries tag, which you can learn more about [here](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic). This should make the tag ignore the page's URL, which is what you want. You might also want to add the `limit="1"` parameter to that tag as well, to ensure that only one sidebar entry is being rendered.

Please let me know if neither of those answers help!

Comment: I agree with Bitmanic - it's probably related to your URL and you need to set dynamic="no". I'd also be surprised if the second "recent posts" code pulls back more than 1 entry.

Comment: Thanks Peter and Bitmanic - I tried dynamic and limit parameters with values you suggested. But no luck in fixing the problem. I just edited the code to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The best strategy would be to move what's in your snippet into a separate template file while you try to figure this out. I noticed a couple of things that seem off to me in your sidebar snippet code.

```
<div id="ebook_offer">
{exp:channel:entries channel="test"}
<h3>Ebook</h3>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</div>

<div id="about_blog">
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog_sidebar"}
        <h3>About Obsia's Blog</h3>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

This doesn't really seem the right way to use the {exp:channel:entries} tag. You mentioned "ebook_offer" was a channel field. But here you're using it as a static id for an HTML div. If "ebook_offer" is a field I would expect something like this:

```
<h3>Ebook</h3>
{exp:channel:entries channel="test"}
    {ebook_offer}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Same with "about_blog"

```
<h3>About Obsia's Blog</h3>
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog_sidebar"}
    {about_blog}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Also I noticed you said the channel was named "sidebar" but in your {exp:channel:entries} tag you're using "blog_sidebar". Which isn't the same thing, is your channel's shortcode "sidebar" or "blog_sidebar"?

Finally this is a little off to me

```
<div id="demo" dynamic="no" limit="1">
</div>
```

"dynamic" and "limit" only work on ExpressionEngine {exp:channel:entries} tags, not regular HTML elements (like DIVs). I would try using Bitmanic and Peter's suggestion again, but apply it to {exp:channel:entries} like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog_sidebar" dynamic="off"}
...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If you're new to ExpressionEngine I highly recommend videos & tutorials by Ryan Ireland http://eeinsider.com/videos

Comment: Made the corrections - some of them were due to oversight. Problem is it still does not work but it works if I replace channel = "blog_sidebar" with "blog". In short it does display content from blog channels but not blog_sidebar channels - any clue?

Comment: In that case, I would imagine that your issue has to do with how you set up the blog_sidebar channel. I can't think of  any particular settings that would stop your channel entries from displaying on a page, unfortunately.Are you sure you've been saving entries to the blog_sidebar channel?

Comment: yes I checked that - that was my conclusion but not sure what the problem is. Thank you Patrick, Bitmanic and Peter.